# jQuery UI namespaceWidget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I'm looking over the `ui.dialog` source code, which is probably the best learning experience ever.

I see they reference `uiDialog` a lot, and it seems clear that uiDialog reefers to the widget itself.  So I tried this in my widget, as in `namespaceWidgetName` but it's undefined.  Do I understand `uiDialog` correctly, and how do I reefer to my widget within the widget?

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

    $.widget("dbd.myWidgetName", {
        options: {
            //autoOpen: true,
        },
        _create: function() {
        },
        widget: function() {
             return this.dbdMyWidgetName;
        }
// rest of widget code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `_create` function of ui.dialog there is a line that reads:

```
uiDialog = (self.uiDialog = $('<div></div>'))
```

This is how the `uiDialog` property is initialized.

Depending on how your widget works, you might not need to provide a `widget` property/function. Many jQuery widgets do not. The `dialog` widget creates some DOM content that wraps the element you specify in `$.dialog()`, and its `widget` property/function enables you to access that DOM element.

If you want to provide a `widget` property to be consistent with `dialog`, you could simply use the underlying `element` of your widget like this:

```
$.widget("dbd.myWidgetName", {
    options: {
        //autoOpen: true,
    },
    _create: function() {
    },
    widget: function() {
         return this.element;
    }
}
```

All jQuery widgets have a property called `element` that refers to the underlying DOM element(s), wrapped in a jQuery instance. Take a look in a debugger to see how it works.

Comment: so variables defined with `var myVariable =` in `_create` are available throughout the widget?  Is this true for variables defined elsewhere?

Comment: Seems to not be the case.. I did `var dbdMyWidgetName = $('<div id="mywidget"/>');` in `_create` but dbdMyWidgetName wasn't available in any other method.

Comment: To clarify a little `uiDialog = (self.uiDialog = $('<div></div>')).appendTo(document.body) .... )` is where the magic happens...notice: `uiDialog = (self.uiDialog = $('<div></div>')`

Comment: The `self` variable is a common technique I have noticed in jQuery widgets. Most of my widget methods by convention begin with `var self = this;` so that `self` is the current widget (`this` can refer to other objects, e.g. when you write handler closures, so using `self` avoids confusion). As you have noted, you can use `self.myprop` to add properties to the widget, which is a handy way to store information or cache jQuery element references.